# How to push child arrays into items in an array to local React state, via a Firebase snapshot

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, state

The state in this little app is set by looping over the items in a Firebase snapshot (array). I can't figure out how to output a nested (child) array in this way. My gut says it's a regular JS function that I'm not thinking of like `map` and that I'm confused based on learning the syntax for state. I'd love some help in figuring out how to push the `sessions` arrays into state with each `exercise`.

Screenshot of the data structure in Firebase: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKiak.png

```
componentDidMount () {
const exercisesRef = firebase.database().ref('exercises')
exercisesRef.on('value', snapshot => {
  let exercises = snapshot.val()
  let newState = []
  for (let exercise in exercises) {
    newState.push({
      id: exercise,
      title: exercises[exercise].title,
      setting: exercises[exercise].setting,
      settingType: exercises[exercise].settingType,
      reps: exercises[exercise].reps,
      raiseAfter: exercises[exercise].raiseAfter,
      raiseBy: exercises[exercise].raiseBy
    })
  }
  this.setState({
    exercises: newState
  })
})
```

}

Thank you in advance for any help you can give!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the JSON formatting that you provided, it seems like

```
let exercise in exercises
```

is providing you with each exercise as an object.

If that's the case, you should be able to just push exercise into newState directly, which would give you access to the sessions object within the exercise object.

Comment: Did this help at all?

Comment: It does make sense and it's gotten me closer. I'm reading through other posts on how to push an object literal into an array.

Comment: `exercises` returns as an object and `exercise` in `let exercise in exercises` returns only the UID generated by Firebase for each `exercise`, so I'm digging further.

Comment: I'm marking this as the correct answer because it led to the right way for me to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else runs into this issue, @Claysmile was right. Pushing the whole object into state and it seems that using Lodash's map function is the best for outputting data.

```
exercisesRef.on("value", snapshot => {
  this.setState({ exercises: snapshot.val() });
});
```

For outputting the data, in this specific example I'm using:

```
<ul>
  {sessions &&
    map(sessions, (session, key) =>
      <li key={key}>
        <p>
          {session.completed}
        </p>
        <p>
          {session.completedDate}
        </p>
        <p>
          {session.setting}
        </p>
      </li>
    )}
  </ul>
```

For my fellow front-enders, the `<p>`s are just placeholders, don't worry. :)